# Distribution of a product of a matrix with a random matrix

Tags: distributions, matrix, multivariate-distribution, random-matrix

Suppose we have the matrices $Z\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ and $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$, such that each row $x_i\in\mathbb{R}^d$ is drawn i.i.d  from a $N(0,\Sigma_{d\times d})$ distribution. What is the distribution of $ZX$?

Would it be,

\begin{equation}
ZX\stackrel{?}{\sim} N\left(0,Z_{n\times n}\otimes \Sigma_{d\times d}\right)
\end{equation}

Comment: As a quick reality check, contemplate your solution when $n=d=1.$